# IE10 / Windows 8 weird outline and box-shadow effect on all elements

Tags: html, css, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

If anyone can help with this, it'd be super. I'm having weird rendering issues on IE10/Win8. Everything works fine in all other browsers including IE10/Win7 but IE10/Win8 displays weird outlines or box-shadows on all elements when selected or hovered over.

I've tried setting all elements `(*)` to `outline:none` or `outline:transparent` on `*:active, *:focus, *:hover` to no avail. I've also disabled transitions but the effect still appears. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap with other custom styles. All transitions take place through Bootstrap though.

IE10 does not support conditional statements so I ran the following script to add an ie10 class to the html and add styles specific to IE10.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if( ($.browser.msie) && ($.browser.version == "10.0") ){
        $('html').addClass('ie10');
    }

});
```

Still doesn't work. I've attached screenshots of the issue I'm facing (only IE10 / Win 8).

[image: Artifacts on background image]

[image: Border or outline on h3 tag]

[image: Clicking input box causes weird shadow/outline transition]

[image: Anchor tags / buttons also get a weird outline]

Here's some sample code for the text box:

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-placeholder">
    <input autofocus="autofocus" class="input-medium" id="user_full_name" name="user[full_name]" size="30" tabindex="1" type="text" value="Sagar Patil">
    <a href="#" class="error-msg hide" rel="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="" tabindex="104" data-original-title=""></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.input-placeholder {
position: relative;
}

#profile .input-medium, #local-testing .input-medium {
width: 344px;
color: #a16d1d;
padding: 10px 13px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-ms-border-radius: 3px;
-o-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

*Bootstrap styles*

```
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
background: #fdf7ed;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
-ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
-o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
-webkit-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
-moz-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
-ms-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
-o-transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
transition: border linear .2s,box-shadow linear .2s;
}

select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
padding: 13px;
margin-bottom: 13px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
border: 1px solid #a4875d;
color: #a16d1d;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-ms-border-radius: 6px;
-o-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Below are the styles for the green buttons:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col3 pull-right">
    <a href="#" class="plan_choose btn btn-modal-plan btn-upgrade" data-planinfo="Power Corporate|$350|50 users||45" data-product-type="live_testing" id="plan_45">Upgrade</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.plans div[class*="col"] {
float: left;
}

.plans .col3 {
width: 94px;
}

.btn-upgrade, .btn-repurchase, .modal-body .btn-upgrade, .modal-body .btn-repurchase {
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
background-color: #719a49;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#719a49,#4d6a31);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#719a49),to(#4d6a31));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#719a49,#4d6a31);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#719a49,#4d6a31);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#719a49,#4d6a31);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#719a49,#4d6a31);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border: 1px solid #344a1e;
-ms-filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff719a49',endColorstr='#ff4d6a31',GradientType=0);
}
```

*Bootstrap styles*

```
.btn {
border-color: #c5c5c5;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15) rgba(0,0,0,0.15) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.btn-modal-plan {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
width: 92px;
height: 27px;
line-height: 27px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
float: right;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-ms-border-radius: 6px;
-o-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
-ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
-o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
```

Any help figuring out what is going on and how to fix it would be much appreciated. Have tried everything including resetting `outline` and `border` styles to `transparent` and `none` for `active, focus and hover` states for all elements if the browser is ie10. No luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Please post the related CSS code

Comment: The screen shots are really useful - but having the simplest example in HTML and CSS that demonstrates the problem would be even more so.

Comment: Have you traced the styles using IE developer tools (with an offending element selected)?

Comment: @Mr_Green I've added code snippets for the text input box and the green buttons.

Comment: @TimMedora Yup. Tried that. Still no luck. It's tricky because when the develop panel or Flashbug Lite is open, the problem disappears completely and behaves normally. However, once the debug panels are closed, the issues start appearing again.

Comment: Steve's fiddle looks okay in IE 10 on the MS Surface (closest thing I have to a Windows 8 machine) and of course on Windows 7. The only things that come to mind are 1) validating the document (sometimes structural errors can manifest in bizarre ways and 2) start removing CSS until the problem goes away and narrow down the cause.

Comment: @TimMedora Gotcha. Have already gone down that route but will start removing individual styles. I have a feeling it's a problem with the transition and box-shadow effects. Thanks for looking into this though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [play to see if I could recreate this](http://jsfiddle.net/xVNGH/1/).

The idea that jumps to mind is that Internet Explorer is adding styles to images inside of anchors, so you could stop this using...

```
a img {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: IE10 puts a big blue border around the image inside an anchor...at least on Windows 7. Which is indeed different than the default behavior of other browsers.

Comment: @Steve Fenton So i'm using Eric Meyers CSS reset to reset all the borders and outlines to 0. Using the snippet of code mentioned above, I've also added resets for borders specifically for ie10. Still no dice. I'm assuming the resets propagate down to the `a img` elements too? I'll add some code snippets to make this easier to debug.

Comment: @SteveFenton I've added CSS and HTML snippets for the input box and the green buttons. I think if any one of these is solved, I can figure out how to solve the others or can replicate the solution for other elements. Let me know if there is anything else that might make it easier to debug.

Comment: Based on your CSS I can't recreate the problem... http://jsfiddle.net/xVNGH/3/ - using Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16438 on Windows 7.

Comment: @SteveFenton It works fine on Windows 7. The problem is only IE10/Windows 8. Thanks for trying anyways. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you see the problem in that JSFiddle page? If so, I will try and find a Windows 8 box and have another look.

Comment: @SteveFenton Doesn't seem to appear on the fiddle. Could be that the remaining code across the site is affecting the final output. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like it - we haven't captured the problem with the example code.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it.

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

I found this on my `.modal-content` bootstrap class and this is what was causing the issue.

Remove this property and all your problems should disappear.